# Can I run conduit in an open ceiling on top of the bottom part of the rafters in a commercial building?

Tags: electrical

Wiring an old pole barn to be used as a commercial building

Comment: What State do you live in?

Answer (score 1):

You can run most any rigid, PVC and or EMT conduit as this is a dry location it will need to be secured within 3' of the box and depending on size anchored to the rafter every 10' feet. I just double checked the support for PVC in the smaller size is 3', I don't use PVC very often but it is very easy to install. Code may require this to be done by an electrician because it is commercial. A home owner can do all there own work but when it goes industrial or commercial depending on local code it may require a licensed electrician.

Comment: Whether a home owner can do their own work depends on jurisdiction. In many places, not.

Comment: Bib, I am not sure what you are saying, I have lived in 5 states and all 5 it was 100% legal for a home owner to do there own wiring right down to installing the service. if it is a rental , commercial, or industrial application then the owner is required to have the work completed by an electrician in most cases. I have also worked in 3 additional states for direct family members in states were I did not have a license and they were all permitted jobs that had no problems.

Comment: @EdBeal Sounds like this is a commercial application. "*...used as a commercial building*".

Comment: In New York City (and I believe some other jurisdictions) homeowners are not permitted to do their own electrical (or plumbing) work.

Comment: I agree and added the license concern within 1 minute of posting my answer. Of all the states I have lived in only 1 allowed the owner to do commercial work but I think that has changed now (that was 32 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the usage of the building, EMT is acceptable on the tops of the chords of the trusses for commercial installations in most areas.

Rigid conduit is always acceptable in any installation that is not corrosive.

You should double check with your local authority to see if EMT is good enough. You may be able to use MC or AC cable in your area. It is fine by the Code. Cheaper and easier to run.

Best to ask your local inspector.

Good luck!